# How to add a shortcut icon in the notification area?

Tags: windows-7

How to add icons/items in the notification area?

I want to make a shortcut in the notification area rather than the task bar.

Comment: Items like what? What do you expect these things to do, apart from just sitting there?

Comment: Some installed software such as games.

Comment: So, you want to able to click an icon and then *start* a game? (Hence, turn the notification area into being some quick launch as well?) Or do you want to minimise *running* games into the notification area rather than to the task bar? We're not mind readers here! ;-) (And please note the "edit" link underneath your question. So far, in my opinion, is't still not a real question!)

Comment: I want to make a shortcut in notification area rather than the task bar. :p

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no built in way to create a shortcut in the notification area.  The notification area doesn't show shortcuts - it displays applications that register themselves for notifications.  You may be able to find some software that will do what you want.

A couple of options:

1. Built into Windows, if you right-click the Taskbar and choose Toolbars you can add a new tool bar (that will be shown as a pop menu).  You can add the contents of the desktop or point it to a new folder.  Fill that folder with shortcuts and they will display.
2. Otherwise you need to find an application that will let you create shortcuts.  Stuff I found searching (not recommending any of them)

   ```
    http://desktoptraylauncher.prv.pl/
    http://www.pssoftlab.com/pstf_info.phtml
    http://www.activetray.com/
    http://www.softwaregeek.com/dock-system-tray-launcher/p1.html
   ```

Answer (score 2):

After reading [shf301](https://superuser.com/users/7745/shf301)'s answer, I found Windows 7 lets you position a Toolbar alongside the taskbar, which does provide similar functionality to adding shortcuts to the notification area in a vertically positioned taskbar.

[image: Toolbar shortcuts are on the right with names below the icons]

Answer (score 0):

Use [Tray Tool](http://www.gregorybraun.com/TRAYTOOL.ZIP). After installing you will find a small red box icon in system tray. open it an add your program , then u can run that program in system tray. I used this program many years ago , don't know if it works now.

Comment: Says it works on Vista too!...http://gregorybraun.com/TrayTool.html

Comment: doesnt work on windows7